# PPT = Using Section Names

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to display the section name in a textbox on (each) slide so this can be communicated to the viewer?
as shown in:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ppt-using-section-names-in-footer/2b844798-2afa-4216-9ba5-5d066ac4dcca
But I can't use the footer as it's already used elsewhere.

Edit: @ Steve Rindsberg - Thank you very much for your Answer.
(Sorry for mistakes. I am a beginner in VBA (since two weeks - but many hours…).
Here is my code: First, I tried the following:
I added a textbox as placeholder to a SlideMaster.CustomLayout with the text "Section#".

```
Sub AddTextboxToSlidemaster()
Dim shp As Shape
On Error Resume Next
Set shp = Application.ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1).Shapes.AddPlaceholder(ppPlaceholderObject,  _
Left:=223.75, Top:=9#, Width:=453.62, Height:=12.18898)
With shp
    shp.Tags.Add "TEXT", "Section#"  'this seems to be unnecessary
       With .TextFrame
            .TextRange.Text = "Section#"
       With .TextRange
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Font.name = "Verdana"
                .Font.Color.RGB = RGB(7, 37, 62)
                .ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoFalse
           End With
       End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Then I copied this placeholder/textbox into a few relevant customlayouts. 
Next I added some slides with one of these custom layouts (in the slideView). So I have this placeholder/textbox on some slides.

Next step: I search for the text "Section#" in all slides and tag these placeholders with the tag "TEXT", Value "Section#":

```
Sub FindTextSelectionAndTag()
For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            Set foundText = txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="Section#")
            Do While Not (foundText Is Nothing)
                With foundText
                shp.Tags.Add "TEXT", "Section#"
        Set foundText = _
                        txtRng.Find(FindWhat:="Section#", _
                        After:=.Start + .Length - 1)
              End With
            Loop
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

But the placeholders on the slides do not accept this tag.

So instead of this I set the textbox with the text " Section#" direct on some relevant slides - as you have suggested - and then I run the macro to tag the textbox:
"Sub FindTextSelectionAndTag()" as described above.

Finally, I create that macro, which brings the current section to the categorized/tagged text box.

```
Sub AbschnittHeader()
  Dim sld As Slide
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim b_found As Boolean
    If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count > 0 Then
      For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
      For Each shp In sld.Shapes
  If shp.Tags("TEXT") = "Section#" Then _
  shp.TextFrame.TextRange = 
 ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.name(sld.sectionIndex)
     Next shp
   Next sld
 End If
End Sub
```

That works so far.

I would ask for possible optimizations in that code - and I have the question, what is wrong with adding the placeholder on theMasterslide.customlayout. Is there a way to make this work - because I think this way would be more comfortable. Or ist this impossible for this purpose.

I would also like to add the name of the PowerPoint file (ActivePresentation) additionally to the section in the textbox as follows (but I dont' not know how):

Name of powerpoint file | sld.sectionIndex

For example (Name of pptFile: Marketing):
Marketing | Chapter 1 Introduction
Marketing | Chapter 2…

I appreciate your advice.

Comment: The code in the link you posted will provide the name of the section each slide belongs to. From there all you need to do is use the slide's .Shapes.AddTextbox method to add a textbox wherever you'd like. You can then format it to taste and add the section name as the textbox shape's .TextFrame.TextRange.Text property.  Have a go at it, post your code back here and we can help with any problems.

Comment: Thank you. I have taken your advice into account, posted my code and edited my question.

Comment: A question for you:  why do you want to add text/placeholders to the custom layouts?  Is there some reason not to add the text to each slide instead?

Comment: There are a few slides in which the section should not appear, e.g. source directory, table of contents. If it's complicated to use the customlayouts, I can also manually delete the text boxes. No problem. I just thought it would be easier with the custom layouts.

Comment: In those cases, I think I'd use a special custom layout and have the code skip adding the text box to slides that are based on that layout.  I'd *definitely* keep tagging the shapes you're adding, so that you can also write a routine that searches for and deletes any shape with the same tag in case you later need to remove or update the text.

Comment: This is a helpful proposal. Also, I'm going to tag the text boxes as this is very useful. Do you also have a hint to include the name of the file or perhaps the title on the first slide into the textbox?

Comment: Again, I'd add a text box to hold the filename/title and tag it so you can edit/delete/restore it later. ActivePresentation.Name will give you the current presentation's file name, ActivePresentation.FullName will give you the full path + file name. How to get the title instead?  That will depend on what you mean by the title!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. This is now my final solution that works:
First Sub AddTextboxToSlides() as described in my question - but not to the master but to several slides - and then Sub AbschnittHeader() optional with the following lines:

a. Included with the file name

```
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
  If shp.Tags("TEXT") = "Section#" Then _
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange = ActivePresentation.FullName _
    & " | " & ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.name(sld.sectionIndex)
```

b. or included with the "file title" from the first slide :-)

```
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
  If shp.Tags("TEXT") = "Section#" Then _
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange = _
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
    & " | " & ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.name(sld.sectionIndex)
```